# Checkbox beside label as table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have a `<input type="checkbox">` beside a `<label>` ,

I want to get them as `display: table-cell` , but still they are on the same "column" , How to make it as the correct way ?

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300;
  height: 200px;
  display: table
}
  
.asRow {
  display: table-row;
}
  
.asCell {
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper asTable">
  <div class="asRow">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="C1" class="asCell">
    <label class="checkboxLabel" for="C1" class="asCell">I'm 1 - Started several           mistake joy say painful             removed reached end. State burst think end       are its. Arrived off she elderly beloved him affixed                 noisier         yet. An course regard to up he hardly. View four has said does men saw find           dear shy. Talent           men wicket add garden.           
    </label> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the displaying I try to get -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to turn them into table-cell but anyway is this what you want?

I'm giving the checkbox a `float: left` and turning the label into a block.

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 300;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
}

.asRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.asCell {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
}

.checkboxLabel{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper asTable">
<div class="asRow">
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="C1" class="asCell">
 <label class="checkboxLabel" for="C1" class="asCell">
  I'm 1 - Started several mistake joy say painful             removed reached end. State burst think end are its. Arrived off she elderly beloved him affixed                 noisier yet. An course regard to up he hardly. View four has said does men saw find dear shy. Talent           men wicket add garden.           
 </label> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give both your **label** and **checkbox** `float: left;` then give your label a specific width;

```
.asCell, .checkboxLabel {
 float: left;
}

.checkboxLabel {
 width: 500px;
}
```